# create custom Select input with Custom Options with css

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, input

i have a project.i want create a select input with options like this picture and I prefer all code to be written in the html and css and if neede use vanilla js.
but No matter how hard I tried, I did not succeed.I stuck specially in style of options part.i searched in google but i can't find my desired result.

[image]

this is my code

```css
body {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100vh;
    background: #eee;
    direction: rtl;
}
/* Reset Select */
select {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    -ms-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    outline: 0;
    box-shadow: none;
    border: 1px solid darkgray;
    background: #eee;
    background-image: none;
}
/* Remove IE arrow */
select::-ms-expand {
    display: none;
}
/* Custom Select */
.select {
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    width: 170px;
    height: 46px;
    line-height: 3;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
select {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 0 .5em;
    color: #333;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
/* Transition */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport"
          content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="select">
    <select name="select" id="select">
        <option selected disabled>Choose an option</option>
        <option value="1">Pure CSS</option>
        <option value="2">No JS</option>
        <option value="3">Nice!</option>
    </select>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i very very appreciate if any one can help me.i realy realy need it.

Comment: Styling a native `<select/>` to some degree is possible-- styling the dropdown on a native select is very much a different situation.  Would it be acceptable to eschew the native `<select/>` element and instead create one with `<div/>`s, JavaScript, and ARIA?

Comment: it means it is't possible created this style with select and options? @AlexanderNied

Comment: I'm not sure which styles you are having trouble applying. I was interpreting your question as how to create these elements avoiding js.

Comment: I have no problem with vanilla js. Something that is important to me this is it that this element created with select and options.I wanted use css only for simplicity but if you can created this style with js I appreciate you @AsyncAwaitFetch

Answer (score 0):

I don't like how there is a scroll bar over the border and it would be easy to fix, but it is the same as your picture. You would need to find a font that matches the picture, and a new icon maybe svg for the down / up content on the label. Hopefully this is a good starting point for you.

```js
const $ = str => [...document.querySelectorAll(str)];

$(".label").forEach(label => {
  label.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const targetLabel = e.target;
    const targetDropdown = targetLabel.parentElement;
    const targetItemContainer = targetDropdown.querySelector(".itemContainer");
    targetItemContainer.classList.toggle("hidden");
    targetLabel.classList.toggle("up");
  });
});

$(".item").forEach(item => {
  item.addEventListener("click", e => {
    const targetItem = e.target;
    const targetItemContainer = targetItem.parentElement;
    const targetDropdown = targetItemContainer.parentElement;
    const targetLabel = targetDropdown.querySelector(".label");
    targetLabel.innerText = targetItem.innerText;
    targetItemContainer.classList.add("hidden");
    targetLabel.classList.remove("up");
  });
});
```

```css
.dropdown {
  direction: rtl;
  display: inline-block;
}

  .dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
  }

  .dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #f1f1f1; 
  }

  .dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background: #888; 
  }

  .dropdown ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
    background: #555; 
  }

.label {
  padding: 1em;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 100px;
  user-select: none;
}

.label::before {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1em;
  content: "";
}

.up::before {
  content: "";
}

.itemContainer {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.item {
  padding: 1em;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.item:hover {
  background-color: rgb(240, 240, 250);
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="dropdown">
  <div class="label">ايبسوم</div>

  <div class="itemContainer hidden">
    <div class="item">يوضع في</div>
    <div class="item">يتم ازالة</div>
    <div class="item">الكلاسيكي</div>
    <div class="item">فرانكوا اراب</div>
    <div class="item">يوضع في</div>
    <div class="item">يتم ازالة</div>
    <div class="item">الكلاسيكي</div>
    <div class="item">فرانكوا اراب</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please note that this solution lacks accessibility for keyboard-only or screenreader users-- you would need to add that manually and would require leveraging some ARIA to this end.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ARIA, usually building apps for internal use. If you have any resources to recommend I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: 1) [MDN Page for ARIA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA) 2) [WAI-ARIA Dropdown Example Implementation](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-practices-1.1/examples/listbox/listbox-collapsible.html) 3) An article I wrote: [An Unreasonably Long Introduction To ARIA (With Example Implementation)](https://awnied.medium.com/accessibility-series-an-unreasonably-long-introduction-to-aria-with-example-implementation-833ac68c0bac)

Comment: Also, for what it is worth, please note-- you may be building apps for internal use, but many disabilities are hidden, and you may not know that people are affected by them.  Even for internal apps it is probably wise to strive to make things maximally accessible; you certainly wouldn't want to preclude the hiring of somebody who needs to use assistive web browsing technology because you haven't made your workplace adequately accessible...

Comment: will be good to learn more about accessibility, thanks for the resources.

Comment: considering rule 1 seems to be not using ARIA, would it be possible to have the div interface interact with a `select` element invisible to eye but available to accessibility devices? I am reading about ARIA, and if you have time to suggest an edit to my post which includes ARIA compliance, I would find value in that.